# Relax-and-Recover Bootable Image Types that work with the Raspberry Pi?

Tags: raspbian, boot, image, backup, multiboot

Are there any bootable image types that Relax-and-Recover creates that could be booted and used to restore the system layout on a Raspberry Pi / Jesse 8?

I know that the system layout of the SD Card on the Raspberry Pi isn't at all similar to that of a PC, and as far as I know, you can't use a BIOS or anything to select between a REAR bootable image and the SD Card containing Jesse 8; or even to boot an image on PXE; so you'd almost have to have an SD Card that would overwrite itself with the system layout, and that doesn't sound to me like it would work.

P.S. I saw something called [berry-boot](http://www.berryterminal.com/doku.php/berryboot) in the tags, would that work?

Comment: Something like this maybe? http://www.berryterminal.com/doku.php/berryboot/adding_custom_distributions

Comment: It looks like .img files and .iso are interchangeable provided an .img is uncompressed.

https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-difference-between-an-iso-file-and-an-img-file